# How to get the second order derivation with respect to $x$ of equation (3.28 )?

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

How to get the second order derivation with respect to $x$ of equation (3.28 )?
$$\psi_+(x,k)= e^{ikx}+ \int_{x}^{\infty} K(x,z) e^{ikz}dz \tag{3.28}$$
which is one of the question that mentioned in a book entitled "Solitons : an introduction" by P.G. Drazin and R.S. Johnson.

thanks for the comment, this problem has been solved.

Comment: Try differentiating under the integral sign

Comment: By the way, in math "complex" and "complicated" mean different things. You are not doing "complex-analysis" nor "complex-integration" here.

Comment: thanks for the comment, its very helpful. sorry, i will correct the topic

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, it helpful with problems like this to introduce another variable temporarily that separates the instances that are causing you problems. $k$ is constant here, so I am going to treat it as a parameter, not a variable. Consider the function $$F(u,v) = \int_v^\infty K(u,z)e^{ikz}dz$$
What you have is $f(x) = F(u(x),v(x))$ where $u(x) = x, v(x) = x$. Now, $$\frac {df}{dx} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dx} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dx} = \left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\right|_{(x,x)} + \left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\right|_{(x,x)}$$

Does that clear up your confusion? To get the 2nd derivative, take the same approach again.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but my problem is how to derivate the function with the bottom limit in the integration that mention the x variable

Comment: @megapangastuti - And I just told you what you need to do to accomplish that. Try it. I promise it'll work.

Comment: oke, thaks for the comment

Comment: Unless your problem strictly is "what to do when differentiating with respect to the bottom limit" and not "what to do when the integrand and limit both depend on $x$". If it is just the former, remember that $\int_a^b = - \int_b^a$ and apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.